# Passing attributes or param from js/jsp to backing bean with JSF 1.2

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, jsf-1.2

I'm writing a very simple frontend for an Oracle database. It is based on JSF 1.2, jsp, and deployed on a glassfish-ee-2.1, and developed with NetBeans 6.5.1.

Yeah, I know this is 2012.

One must read the content, maybe update it, and save it back to the db.

It works fine for text based elements. I added binding attributes to my UI Elements, and I can access them from the bean to retrieve the value of various textfields etc.

I am using (this is a requirement?!) the msDropdown component ([official page](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)), based on jquery, which allows on to have a nice dropdown menu with image and text.

As this element is not standard however, I didn't find a way to use a binding attribute to access it form the backing bean.

This means I can't set the text when the page loads, like I can for the text elements, and additionally, I can't get the value of the selected component when processing a submit in the backing bean.

The msDropDown is defined like this in the JSP:

```
<webuijsf:markup>
    <select id="status" name="status" style="left: 150px; top: 62px; width:100px">
        <option data-description="" data-image="base_3.gif" value=""></option>
        <option data-description="" data-image="base_0.gif" value="0"></option>
        <option data-description="" data-image="base_1.gif" value="1"></option>
        <option data-description="" data-image="base_2.gif"  value="2"></option>
    </select>
</webuijsf:markup>
```

I create a js variable that holds my dropdown, to access its value later.

```
<webuijsf:script>
    var oHandler1 = $("#status").msDropdown().data("dd");
    var index = oHandler1.selectedIndex;
</webuijsf:script>
```

Then I try to pass that variable to my backing bean like this:

```
<webuijsf:button actionListenerExpression="#{editApplication.submitUpdate}" actionExpression="#{editApplication.update_action}" id="update"
                                     style="height: 24px; left: 623px; top: 408px; position: absolute; width: 72px" text="Update">
    <f:attribute name="currentIndex" value="#{currentRow.value['APPNAME']}"/>
    <f:attribute name="currentStatus" value="<%=index%>"/>
</webuijsf:button>
```

But I always get the error already reported that the < may not be used in a value.

Any idea how I could get to access that special dropdown from the bean? or pass it its value to the bean for that matter?

Many thanks for your help, and let me know if you nee more code!

Oli from 2006./.

Answer (score 0):

msDropdown works by overhauling a normal html select.  But if you actually insert an html select in your jsf document, you will not have any integration with the jsf lifecycle.

The solution is to use an actual jsf component, the [selectOneMenu](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_selectOneMenu.html) instead.  It will fully integrate in the lifecycle, meaning you don't need any hacks to retrieve the value.  It will submit like any other component on your page.

The `selectOneMenu` renders like a normal html select on the client side, meaning you can use msDropDown with it.  The only difficulty is getting the id of the component.  I suggest using a `styleClass` instead. It will be easier.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="status" styleClass="statusSelect" style="left: 150px; top: 62px; width:100px">
    <f:selectItem itemValue=""></option>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="0"></option>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1"></option>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2"></option>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<webuijsf:script>
  //setup metadata (images and such)
  var $select = $('.statusSelect');
  var children = $select.children('option');
  $(children[0]).data('image','base0.gif');
  //... and so on to add your metadata

  var oHandler1 = $select.msDropdown().data("dd");
  var index = oHandler1.selectedIndex;
</webuijsf:script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After a lot of fiddling around, I managed to get the component to display, but only after I removed the id tag in the selectOneMenu. However, I don't see the element in the Design tab in netbeans, so I can not add a binding attribute that would allow me to get the value in the bean. I'll keep looking for a way...

Comment: And as I don't have an ID, I can't use it in a form of sort. *banging head hard* but nothing comes out ;)

Comment: it should work with the id as well though.  It's strange that it would not display without.  As for the design tab; if your tools are keeping you from doing your job, change the tools :)

Comment: Yeah, I have no problem changing the tools, but one of my hard requirement is working with glassfish 2.1.1, and it is no supported in 7.x release of netbeans ;) - If I add the binding attribute manually using an ID in the selectOneMenu, then I get this error from js when running my app: *Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: status* It does display, but it's empty